# Curl payload breaks on whitespace

Tags: bash, curl

I need to do  a curl POST request like that:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data $TEXT $URL
```

The TEXT variable I have defined like this:

```
TEXT="{\"text\":\"Some text $UUID\"}"
```

As you may note I want to send also a variable named UUID in the payload.

The issue I have is - if I send it like this the whitespaces inside `\"text\":\"Some text $UUID\"` break the curl and if I remove the whitespaces like `\"text\":\"Some-text-$UUID\"`, it works right.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in bash should be quoted, otherwise the value will be broken into tokens based on spaces, tabs, or other characters that happen to be in `IFS`, and then expanded as a glob if it contains `*` or `?` etc.

Try with the below command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "$TEXT" "$URL"
```